# How can I programmatically add website to compatibility list internet explorer 11?

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, compatibility-mode, ie-compatibility-mode

I've tried adding registry entries at:

```
Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Key Path: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\PolicyList\
Value name: sub.companyname.com
Value data: sub.companyname.com
```

However in Internet Explorer 11 this method does not work as it seems the list has moved.

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\PolicyList", "sub.companyname.com", "sub.companyname.com")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that under Windows 8.1 Enterprise/IE11 the entry is a binary one - this is where I see the entries added under Tools/compatibility View Settings in the registry on my system:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData
```

Look for a Binary value called UserFilter - it's a bit hard to read when you look into it but you can tell it holds your entries.

We have several sites we'll need to add to the list so most likely will export the list from a "master" computer then push it through Group Policy Preferences at least once for initial settings.  Unsure how we'll script additional entries at this point so that when users add their "personal" settings we don't overwrite the value but append to it but one thing at a time I guess.

Comment: **A very important note**: if a user clears their Temporary Internet Files and doesn't leave their History intact, this will clear the "ClearableListData" contents, thereby wiping out the Compatibility View list. The proper way to ensure that users don't inadvertently purge your configured Compatibility View entries is to use the solution from @Rolo but it may be prudent to add them to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\PolicyList\somewebsite.com' instead so that all users receive the setting.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but creating the registry key you mention works for me.

Have you tried creating the registry key by hand?

If you are running 32 bit IE 11, you must create the registry key in 32 bit registry hive, if you are running 64 bit IE 11 you bust create the registry key in 64 bit registry hive.

**IE 11 32 bit on:**

Win 32 bit -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies...

Win 64 bit -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Wow6432Node\Software\Policies...

**IE 11 64 bit on:**

Win 32 bit -> Can't install IE 64 bit

Win 64 bit -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies...

**Remember:**

- If you have IE open when you create the registry key, you need to restart it.
- The new domain allowed to use compatibility mode won't be displayed in compatibility view settings list.

Comment: I dont see those locations in the HIVE, can you confirm?

Comment: They don't exists, you have to create them.

Comment: After adding several sites to the list, shouldn't IE create them? I'd like to not have two sources if possible.

Answer (score 0):

W7 – IE11

Hive: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

Key Path: `Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\DisableSiteListEditing`

Right Click on `DisableSiteListEditing`

Modify

Change Value Data from `1` to `0`